# parsing rss description with Ruby Parser

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse a nytimes rss feed with Ruby's parser.

```
nyt_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml'
open(nyt_url) do |rss|
  @nyt_feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
end
```

And in the view file:

```
<h2>New York Times Feed</h2>
<% @nyt_feed.items.each do |item| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to item.title, item.link %>
    <%= item.description %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But what I get out for the description looks something like this:

```
    Since air assaults by the Assad government picked up two weeks ago, 
knocking rebels in the south on their heels, Syrians have been arriving
at refuge camps in Jordan at a rate of about 2,000 a night.<img width='1' height='1' 
src='http://rss.nytimes.com/c/34625/f/642565/s/22f90a36/mf.gif' border='0'/><br/><br/><a 
href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/139263791500/u/0/f/642565/c/34625/s/22f90a36/a2.htm"><img 
src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/139263791500/u/0/f/642565/c/34625/s/22f90a36/a2.img" 
border="0"/></a><img width="1" height="1" 
src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/139263791500/u/0/f/642565/c/34625/s/22f90a36/a2t.img" 
border="0"/>
```

I also have a similar situation with the Washington Post feed.  How do I get the images to actually display, or at least to get just the description part.  Do I have to handle this with regular expressions or is there some method on the parser object that I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

It's not such a good idea to parse XML or RSS (or HTML) just with regular expressions, because it is not so easy to predict all possible nestings of tags.

Typically you would want to use an XML Gem / library to parse your RSS or XML data (like libxml , Nokogiri, Ox) , **but when the XML feed is really large, it eats up a lot of memory**

Try Ox or Nokogiri, and see if that works better for you than regular expressions.

If your feed is very large, and you have many articles in it, you can try to cut-out the items/articles with a regular expression, and then to parse their contents separately with Ox or Nokogiri (this works also nicely when done in a Resque job for parallel processing).